# masking a multidimensional array - numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two identical arrays of size `(2,3,2)`

```
[[[1, 7],
  [2, 8], 
  [3, 9]],

 [[4, 10],
  [5, 11],
  [6, 12]]]
```

stored in a multidimensional array

```
>>> a  =  np.array([[[[ 1,  1],
              [ 7,  7]],

             [[ 2,  2],
              [ 8,  8]],

             [[ 3,  3],
              [ 9,  9]]],

            [[[ 4,  4],
              [10, 10]],

             [[ 5,  5],
              [11, 11]],

             [[ 6,  6],
              [12, 12]]]])

>>> a.shape
(2, 3, 2, 2)
```

I'm trying to mask the sub arrays in `a` with `m`:

```
>>> m  =  np.array([[[1, 0],
                 [0, 0],
                 [1, 1]],

                [[1, 1],
                 [0, 1],
                 [0, 0]]])
```

which should result in:

```
[[[[ 1,  1],
   [ 0,  0]

   [ 0,  0],
   [ 0,  0],

   [ 3,  3],
   [ 9,  9]]

  [[ 4, 4],
   [10, 10],

   [ 0,  0],
   [11,  11],

   [ 0,  0],
   [ 0,  0]]]
```

I tried to use `np.concatenate` and `np.append` eg, `np.prod(np.concatenate([a,m],axis=0))`

but none of my solutions worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the dimensions of `m` so it broadcasts with `a`:

```
In [183]: a*m[...,None]                                                         
Out[183]: 
array([[[[ 1,  1],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 3,  3],
         [ 9,  9]]],


       [[[ 4,  4],
         [10, 10]],

        [[ 0,  0],
         [11, 11]],

        [[ 0,  0],
         [ 0,  0]]]])
```